# Kotlin - Dynamic PropNamingStrategies using Jackson on REST response API

Tags: json, rest, kotlin, jackson

I have some endpoints that will be versioned, and in the new version it will change the json fields returned from CamelCase to SnakeCase.

Today the approach to serialize the response in CamelCase is, we use Jackson, so in each response DTO class we put the @ JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.UpperCamelCaseStrategy::class) annotation.

I'm looking for some way to keep the same DTO for both versions of the endpoint (cause there is no field change, just the camel and snake variation) but manage to apply this variation, i.e.
v1 - FooDTO - CamelCase
v2 - FooDTO - SnakeCase

I didn't want to recreate the same existing dto class just to annotate with CamelCase, does anyone see a possible way?

What have I tried

Using @ RestControllerAdvice I intercepted the response, in the "beforeBodyWrite" using reflection I changed the annotation at runtime, but it had no effect, it continued applying the annotation strategy present in the class

Edit : Using Spring framework

Comment: You can simply configure this on the `ObjectMapper`, no need to change the dto class. So have one `ObjectMapper` with one naming strategy for the old endpoints, and one with the other naming strategy for the new version endpoints.

Comment: Since you mentioned `@RestControllerAdvice` I assume you're using Spring? Then it might be difficult to get this configured correctly. Good luck!